# this.zone.run() - Ngzone error

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, sails.js

I have a problem with sails + sails socket + angular4

> ```
> import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
> import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';
> import { Http } from '@angular/http';
> import * as socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
> import * as sailsIOClient  from 'sails.io.js';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app-tables',
>   templateUrl: './tables.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./tables.component.scss'],
>   animations: [routerTransition()]
> })
> export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {
>   io:any;
>   smartTableData:any;
>
>   constructor(public http: Http, private zone: NgZone) {
>
>       this.io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);
>       this.io.sails.url = "http://localhost:1337";
>
>       this.io.socket.get('/posts', function(resData, jwr) {
>           console.log (resData);
>           return resData;
>
>
>       });
>
>       this.io.socket.on('updateposts', function(data) {
>           this.zone.run(() => {
>               this.smartTableData = data;
>           });
>       });
>
>
> }
>
> ngOnInit() {
>
> }
>
> }
> ```

When the socket broadcasts data, the line this.socket.on("updataposts") is run, but ngZone does not work.

zone.js:196 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

I want to update data to view when receiving socket data. Please help me! 
Thank you!

Comment: Same thing here. Came up out of blue